# study of the convergence of the numerical series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Can anyone tell me if I answered correctly the convergence of this series
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{i+1} - \sqrt{i}}{i}$$
$$= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i(\sqrt{i+1} + \sqrt{i})}
=   \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i ((i+1)^{1/2} + i^{1/2})}
=   \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i (i+1)^{1/2} + i^{3/2}}$$
$$i (i+1)^{1/2} + i^{3/2} \sim i^{3/2} \Rightarrow
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{3/2}} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \biggl(\frac{1}{i}\biggr)^{3/2}$$
$\bigl(\frac{1}{i}\bigr)^{3/2}$ is a general harmonic series with $\alpha$ > 1 so the series converges. I don't know if I applied correctly the asymptotic relationship (I don't know if it's called like that in English) in the denominator.

Comment: Looks fine, you could use $\sqrt{i+1} > \sqrt{i}$ to get $\le \sum_i {1 \over 2} i^{- {3 \over 2}}$.

Comment: where does $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki You are missing a factor $2$ in your equivalent. $i(i+1)^{1/2} \sim_{i\to\infty} i^{3/2}$, so $$i(i+1)^{1/2} + i^{3/2} \sim_{i\to\infty} 2i^{3/2}$$ It does not change the result, but your proof as written is incorrect because of that missing factor 2.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki: You have $i (i+1)^{1 \over 2} + i^{3 \over 2} \ge 2 i^{3 \over 2}$. This way there is no need for $\sim$ arguments.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{1}{i(\sqrt{i+1} + \sqrt{i})}\sim \frac{1}{2i^{3/2}}$$

then refer to limit comparison test with $\sum \frac{1}{i^{3/2}}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that 2 is there because $\sqrt{i+1} \sim i^{3/2}$ and $\sqrt{i} \sim i^{3/2}$ so adding them  $=2i^{3/2}$, am I right?

Comment: Yes of course, even if it is not so important for the convergence.

Comment: Ok, I thought asymptotic substitution can't be done on sums.

Comment: another way is factoring out $ \sqrt i$

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki I wouldn't say it's "asymptotic substitution". It's just limit comparison test